# How to check input date is between now and 7 days in the future?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm making a ticket booking program, and the user must input a date. The date must not be in the past, and must be within the next 7 days.

Here is what I have right now:

```
if( date < DateTime.Now || date > DateTime.Now + 7 )
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please input a date in the next 7 days");
}
```

Comment: You used the `DateTime` tag, so did you try anything with it?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: You can use `<` and `>` with two DateTimes - so create a `DateTime` for now and one for "now + 7 days".

Comment: This is a very broad question. Are you asking how to add a validator to the view/page/form? Are you using model binding? Are you asking about server-side validation? A code example would help.

Comment: Niall, welcome to StackOverflow. Not showing code and/or not showing that you've made any attempt at all is one of the top reasons to get questions closed around here. So please edit your post with what you've tried and what you have problems, with a clearly defined problem, as @Plutonix has shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the frame of what you want:

```
var userinput = new DateTime();
//could use DateTime.Today in place of DateTime.Now depending on situation
if (userinput > DateTime.Now & userinput < DateTime.Now.AddDays(7))
{
    //yay the date works
}
else
{
    //boo date doesn't work
}
```